# Why is one specific file not showing up in my document library?

Tags: windows-7, libraries

In my "Documents" library on Windows 7, one file is not showing up in Windows Explorer.

When I look in `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\blah\blah` all 24 files appear. But when I look in `Libraries > Documents > blah > blah` only 23 show up.

I made a copy of the file and the copy appears.

Refresh doesn't help.

The "Arrange by" setting defaults to "Name". When I change it to "Folder" the extra file appears, but changing it back to "Name" the file disappears again.

How can I make the file appear in all views? Why would it disappear?

EDIT: I deleted the Windows Search Index and things seem to be working again. I say it's a bug in the Search Service.

Comment: anything different about the missing file?  different filetype/extension than the others, vastly different filesize or creation date, anything?

Comment: Only that this file has been edited in the last 24 hours; most other files have not.

Answer (score 2):

Make the copy of the file (the one you made) the one you want to keep, and delete the one that isn't showing up. Then, accept the quirk you've discovered in Windows 7. Hopefully it never happens again. :-)

It'd be nice to know why it's not showing, but my guess is that whatever indexes and keeps track of the folders & files in the library didn't mark down the existence of the file (for whatever random/buggy reason).